# Problema usando time e print

Tags: python-3.x

o seguinte código não funciona de acordo com o esperado usando Python 3.5

```
import time
for letter in "Hello World!!":
    print(letter, end="")
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Ao invés de imprimir cada letra com um curto intervalo de tempo, ele apenas pausa, e no final imprimi todo o texto. Gostaria que me ajudassem

Comment: Colei seu codigo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3) e a execução se deu exatamente como vc deseja, uma letra a cada meio segundo.

Comment: @Sidon Realmente funcionou, mas no meu notebook não funciona, não sei se a versão de alguma coisa a ver

Comment: @Sidon tanto que usando o shell do próprio site do python (python anywhere), esse código apresentado este problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que `end=""` faz cache da escrita em memória e só escreve o conteúdo no fim de todas as escritas. Isto pode ser contornado iniciando o python com `python -u` ou definindo a variável de ambiente `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`.

Uma alternativa mais simples é forçar a saída para a consola utilizando o parâmetro flush no print:

```
import time
for letter in "Hello World!!":
    print(letter, end="", flush=True) #flush agora forçado aqui
    time.sleep(.5)
```

A solução de `flush=True` apenas funciona na versão 3.3 para cima

Comment: Obrigado!! Funcionou usando este parâmetro